# Custom getters and setters in Rails without Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of `Airports` which have a `region` "property". I had previously managed the `region` property with a method, `Airport#region` that looked up a `Region` object based on properties of the airport.

I've now added a formal relationship so that `Airport belongs_to :region`. 
All my existing `Airports` currently have `nil` `regions`, of course. I've renamed the old `Airport#region` method to `Airport#set_region`.

I want a custom getter that basically does `region ? region : set_region`, aka `region ||= set_region`. But of course then I get a loop.

`region = set_region` gets the job done, but inefficiently, since I imagine it executes `set_region` even if there's already a `region` assigned.

I also want to be able to set a "custom" region if desired (to override whatever `set_region` would "calculate"). The following solutions don't work.

The first one sets the region (visible from a pry session within the method) but not in a way that persists once control returns to the spec it's called from.

```rb
region = reg
save
```

This one just loops.

```rb
update(region: reg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Use `region_id` to get around calling the Rails-provided helper methods, `#region` and `#region=`

```rb
  def region
    if region_id
      Region.find(region_id)
    else
      region = set_region
    end
  end

  def region=(reg)
    update(region_id: reg.id)
  end
```

I'd love to know if anyone knows of different ways to do this.

I'd also really love to know if there's a way to get `Region.find(nil)` to return `nil` instead of throwing an error so I could just do `Region.find(region_id) || set_region`

EDIT: Answering the question I just asked (you know, two lines ago) -- TADA!!

```rb
  def region
    Region.find_by(id: region_id) || set_region
  end
```